# How to select the most expensive item pr. shelf in Hibernate HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

Im crashing my head against the wall at the moment. Normally i would solve this problem with a subquery in the FROM clause, however that is not allowed in HQL.
I've made a simple example i hope you can help me with.

Given i have det following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.SHELF
  (id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.ITEM
  (id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   price INTEGER NOT NULL,
   description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.SHELF_ITEMS
(shelf_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (shelf_id, item_id)
);
```

And from this i want to select the most expensive item pr. shelf.
I can accomplish that by querying the following statement:

```
SELECT
  shelf.id,
  MAX(item.price)
FROM
  PUBLIC.SHELF as shelf
  INNER JOIN PUBLIC.SHELF_ITEMS as shelfitems ON shelf.id = shelfitems.shelf_id
  INNER JOIN PUBLIC.ITEM as item ON item.id = shelfitems.item_id
GROUP BY shelf.id;
```

However there is ONE more requirement! - I also want the item id and description in the same result set.
So i want something like this:

```
SELECT
  shelf.id,
  item.id,
  item.description,
  MAX(item.price)
FROM
  PUBLIC.SHELF as shelf
  INNER JOIN PUBLIC.SHELF_ITEMS as shelfitems ON shelf.id = shelfitems.shelf_id
  INNER JOIN PUBLIC.ITEM as item ON item.id = shelfitems.item_id
GROUP BY shelf.id;
```

However this resultat in an error stating that i need to add the item.id in the GROUP BY clause, and when i add that i get all rows.

It's like im missing some condition stating that i only want the most expensive ones selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    shelf.id,
    item.id,
    item.description,
    item.price
FROM
    shelf shelf
    INNER JOIN shelf_items shelfitems ON shelf.id = shelfitems.shelf_id
    INNER JOIN item item ON item.id = shelfitems.item_id
WHERE
    item.price = (
        SELECT
            MAX(item_inner.price)
        FROM
            shelf_items shelfitems_inner
            INNER JOIN item item_inner ON item_inner.id = shelfitems_inner.item_id
        WHERE
            shelf.id = shelfitems_inner.shelf_id
    )
```

Comment: Works! Thanks alot!

Comment: Welcome :) As you may have noticed already, if a shelf has multiple items with the same price as the highest price, you'll get multiple rows per shelf, one fore each such item.

Comment: That's true! Thank for the notice!

Answer (score 1):

A pure HQL/JPQL solution returning entities, assuming mappings are done correctly, `Shelf` in a *many-to-many* with `Item`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<Shelf, Item> getShelvesWithMaxItemPrice(){
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT sh, it FROM Shelf sh join sh.items it WHERE it.price = "
            + "(SELECT MAX(itInner.price) FROM Item itInner join itInner.shelves shInner WHERE shInner.id = sh.id)");
    List<Object[]> queryResults = query.getResultList();
    Map<Shelf, Item> results = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(Object[] row: queryResults) {
        results.put((Shelf) row[0], (Item) row[1]);
    }
    return results;
}
```

This will generate the same SQL as **Ashutosh A**'s answer.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but thanks for posting! Will probably help someone in the future :)